# How can I get the youngest objects from SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Each row in my table has a date. The date is not unique. The same date is present more than one time.
I want to get all objects with the youngest date.

My solution work but I am not sure if this is a elegent SQLAlchemy way.

```
query = _session.query(Table._date) \
            .order_by(Table._date.desc()) \
            .group_by(Table._date)
# this is the younges date (type is date.datetime)
young = query.first()

query = _session.query(Table).filter(Table._date==young)
result = query.all()
```

Isn't there a way to put all this in one query object or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [having clause](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.having), and you need to import the `max` function
then your query will be:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

stmt = _session.query(Table) \
               .group_by(Table._date) \
               .having(Table._date == func.max(Table._date)
```

This produces a sql statement like the following.

```
SELECT my_table.* 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY my_table._date 
HAVING my_table._date = MAX(my_table._date)
```

If you construct your sql statement with a `select`, you can examine the sql produced in your case using. *I'm not sure if this would work with statements `query`

```
str(stmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this using a sub-query:

```
# @note: do not need to alias, but do in order to specify `name`
T1 = aliased(MyTable, name="T1")

# version-1:
subquery = (session.query(func.max(T1._date).label("max_date"))
            .as_scalar()
            )
# version-2:
subquery = (session.query(T1._date.label("max_date"))
            .order_by(T1._date.desc())
            .limit(1)
            .as_scalar()
            )

qry = session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable._date == subquery)
results = qry.all()
```

The output should be similar to:

```
# version-1
SELECT my_table.id AS my_table_id, my_table.name AS my_table_name, my_table._date AS my_table__date
FROM my_table
WHERE my_table._date = (
    SELECT max("T1"._date) AS max_date
    FROM my_table AS "T1")

# version-2
SELECT my_table.id AS my_table_id, my_table.name AS my_table_name, my_table._date AS my_table__date
FROM my_table
WHERE my_table._date = (
    SELECT "T1"._date AS max_date
    FROM my_table AS "T1"
    ORDER BY "T1"._date DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
    )
```